# Does APEX language support ES256 algorithm?

Tags: apex, jwt, crypto

I'm trying to implement social login via Apple.
When requesting an access token, I get an "invalid_client" error.

I found that one cause for this issue is a bad-formatted JWT, which is required to get an access token from Apple. Moreover, the algorithm used to sign the JWT **has to be** `ES256` (https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ES256), as per Apple specifications.

Digging further, I found a blog post where the author explains that "some JWT libraries don’t support elliptic curve methods", which `ES256` is indeed.

My question is, does the `Crypto.sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey)` method actually implements the `ES256` algorithm if its `algorithmName` param is `ECDSA-SHA256`, meaning EC algorithm which precisely uses `P-256` curve and `SHA-256` hash algorith?

Thank you

Comment: Having a look at the documentation for [the sign() method in the Crypto class][1], their description for ECDSA-SHA256 is "ECDSA signature of an SHA256 hash".  ECDSA does indeed use elliptic curves - but they don't specify which curve, just apparently that the hash is SHA-256.  I want to say that if no one responds here, contact Salesforce support, but I don't know if they'd have that answer for you...


  [1]: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

Comment: @VictorL. actually I noticed the same lack of information in their documentation and was about to open a case on SF

Comment: @identigral Just curious, where did you find this out?  Is it documented somewhere or have you run into this yourself?

Comment: @identigral Okay, but how do you know?  I have seen no documentation indicating what curve(s) its ECDSA algorithms do or do not use.

Comment: @VictorL and OP: ECDSA signature does not "use" a curve, the latter is used for constructing the private/public key. Translation: any EC curve and properly generated + encoded keys based on this curve will work. We're able to generate and verify messages with ES256. To OP's question - is Apex capable of this? With keys generated outside of the SF platform and in the right format - sure.  Our stance is that [implementing crypto on your own is very risky](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209652/why-is-it-wrong-to-implement-myself-a-known-published-widely-believed-to-be).

Comment: @identigral So can it SIGN with curves: P-256, P-384 or P-521 or ENCRYPT using ECDH-ES+A128KW/ECDH-ES+A192KW/ECDH-ES+A256KW ? Documentation here isn't so clear https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_methods

Comment: @compski Sign and verify signature - yes. Encrypt/decrypt - AES is the only supported algo.

Comment: @DavidKohelet So what did SF support say? curious

Comment: Idea: [The Ability to create Elliptic Curve 256 (EC256) key in APEX](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000QLfe1UAD/the-ability-to-create-elliptic-curve-256-ec256-key-in-apex)